# Regular Expression Validator -Not taking lower case alphabets

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a problem with Regular Expression Validator. It takes 0-9, A-Z and prevents ' and " But it not takes lowercase alphabets. Here is my expression `^[a-z|A-Z|0-9|]+[^\"\']*$`

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to match?

Comment: @Mat...I need to enter only a-z ,A-Z and 0-9  to a text box. I don't want single and double quotes also.

Comment: 1) you don't want those `|` symbols there: now you are matching *them* also. 2) this regex matches one or more letters or digits (or |'s) **followed by** zero or more non-quotes.

Comment: @Hans....I need to enter only a-z ,A-Z and 0-9 to a text box. I don't want single and double quotes also....that is my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

The `|` , "OR", should be used in groups `([a-z]|[A-Z|..)`. Also, by adding `[^"']*`, you allow users to enter phrases like `a  @#%$^&&&&*&^&*#$@#$` (starting with alphanumeric character, *followed by any non-quote char*).

My suggested RegEx means:

```
^               <start>
 [a-zA-Z0-9]    Any alplhanumeric character, case-insensitive
            +   at least once
             $  <end>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is that the text contain exclusively letters and digits, you could use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Notice that there is no `|` in the character set, all the things you put inside the `[]` are implicitly "or"ed together. Adding a `|` would allow for a literal `|` in the text.

Change the `+` to `*` if an empty string is valid. You don't need to exclude quotes specifically, since you're not allowing them in at all.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version of similar regexp:

```
^[\w]+$
```

Note: it will also match non-Latin characters and "_", which may be either good or bad depending on your requirements.

Comment: That's not quite the same. That'll match other things like underscores. The `[]` isn't needed either.